# Weblogic server listening on additional port 5001

Tags: weblogic, port

Weblogic managed server is listening on 5001 in adddition to the listen port. Not sure why ? Please advise

Comment: Appservers open up a whole bunch of ports for various purposes. Is this just idle curiosity?

Answer (score 0):

WebLogic Server will typically listen on two ports by default - the configured non-SSL and SSL  ports. You can see log mesages associated with these in WebLogic Server's bootup. (an example is provided a the end of the comment from a WLS 11g domain that only has a HTTP port configured)

Are you running any Fusion Middleware products like OSB or SOA Suite on top of WebLogic Server? These will often have application-specific ports that are used for different purposes.

Also, I'd recommend searching your config.xml for any reference to 5001 - it's possible that there's a network channel configured as part of the domain, or an admin port.

```
####<01/03/2011 6:07:30 PM EST> <Notice> <Server> <danger-room> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <11d1def534ea1be0:36936e7f:12e703dca5f:-8000-000000000000000a> <1298963250040> <BEA-002613> <Channel "Default[3]" is now listening on 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:7001 for protocols iiop, t3, ldap, snmp, http.>
####<01/03/2011 6:07:30 PM EST> <Notice> <Server> <danger-room> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <11d1def534ea1be0:36936e7f:12e703dca5f:-8000-000000000000000a> <1298963250040> <BEA-002613> <Channel "Default[2]" is now listening on 127.0.0.1:7001 for protocols iiop, t3, ldap, snmp, http.>
####<01/03/2011 6:07:30 PM EST> <Notice> <Server> <danger-room> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <11d1def534ea1be0:36936e7f:12e703dca5f:-8000-000000000000000a> <1298963250040> <BEA-002613> <Channel "Default" is now listening on 10.0.2.15:7001 for protocols iiop, t3, ldap, snmp, http.>
####<01/03/2011 6:07:30 PM EST> <Notice> <Server> <danger-room> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <11d1def534ea1be0:36936e7f:12e703dca5f:-8000-000000000000000a> <1298963250040> <BEA-002613> <Channel "Default[1]" is now listening on fe80:0:0:0:a00:27ff:fe8d:6a0f:7001 for protocols iiop, t3, ldap, snmp, http.>
```

Answer (score 0):

With good probability you have installed and activated Hudson CI service in Weblogic. And this service listen to port 5001. For more information you can see [this page](https://programmaticponderings.com/tag/weblogic-server-12c/).